# train acc vs validation acc

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, overfitting, validation, accuracy

i'm working on image segmentation problem in pytorch. using images with two classes ( background and the object to segment).
So I divided the dataset into 3 parts:

- train 50% (199 images)
- val 25% (99 images)
- test 25% (100 images)

after appliynig data augmentation (rotation, random scaling, as well as contrast
gamma adjusting, blure) on train set i've got 1194 images for training.

these are the graphs I got. Does my model have overfitting problem?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer to my question in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3CcfIjycBA&ab_channel=DigitalSreeni

Very clear and simple.

Answer (score 0):

A model is overfitting if the model conforms too closely to your particular choice of training data. In other words, suppose you train a model M. M is overfitting if your metric for model evaluation (in this case accuracy) does **much** better on your *train* set than your *test* set. Now, some reduction in model performance moving from your train set to your test set is expected. Also note that there really is not set in stone rule to determine if your model is overfitting or not, it all depends on how generalizable you want your model to be.

Let me reiterate:
In order to tell if your model is overfitting, you'll need to look at the loss or accuracy of your model on the *train* set and the *test* set.

What you are comparing is the *train* set and the *validation* set. So it's impossible to tell whether your model is overfitting to "seen" data and underperforming on "unseen" data. Recall that the validation set is utilized during the training phase, so in order to test whether your model is overfitting or not, you'll need to compare the train set to the test set. This is because the test set is not a part of the training phase and can be utilized to test for model generalizability.

I hope this helps! Here is an additional resource on validation sets. I highly recommend watching statsquest on YouTube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSytzGwwBVw

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you do not necessarily have an over-fitting problem - it rather depends on what you take over-fitting to mean.  Some would define over-fitting as meaning the performance on the training data is substantially better than the performance on the validation/test data.  However this is not a particularly useful definition as many machine learning methods (e.g. SVMs or deep neural networks) give their best generalisation performance while giving (near) zero error on the training set (see the recent work on ["benign overfitting"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.11300) - see also this [paper](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume21/19-844/19-844.pdf) ).  This seems especially try for high-dimensional problems, such as image recognition.

Most learning algorithms start of minimising the training loss by learning the large scale structure of the data, which also tends to minimise the loss on unseen data (hence improving generalisation), and only later by making changes that are memorising the random variation in the training sample.  This usually has the effect of making generalisation performance worse and worse. As a result, we tend to see something like the diagram below (from Wikipedia), where the training error decreases monotonically, but the error on unseen data initially goes down as the underlying structure is learned, but then starts to rise again as the model is learning the random variation in the training set. This is the idea behind "early stopping".

[image]

I would define over-fitting as meaning that the model had started to learn the random variability in the data, at the expense of an decrease in generalisation performance.  By this definition, I would suggest that your model probably is not overfitting as the generalisation performance is not getting worse.

ETA: the validation loss is increasing slightly, so it appears that may be some mild over-fitting going on.